# itext 7 add multiple images at top of separate pages

Tags: itext7

I have searched multiple similar posts and tried various configuration to achieve this so but couldn't get it working with latest iText 7 libraries.

There are multiple question like this which have been answered but those requirements are not exactly like mine therefore please read read all requirement before marking it as duplicate.

My requirement is to generate a PDF document with multiple images, each positioned at top left corner of individual page (after default margin of 36 units). e.g. if there are 5 images, resulting pdf will have 5 pages (A4 size), each containing one image at top of the page.

I started with iText 7 example available at following link to generate multiple pages.

https://itextpdf.com/en/resources/examples/itext-7/multiple-images

Couple of changes I made are

1. Set Auto Scale true

   `Image image = new Image(imageData).setAutoScale(true);`
2. Add new page with default size.

   `pdfDocument.addNewPage(i+1);`

But in example given at above link adds image at bottom left corner of each page. Therefore I first tried to calculate bottom position but subtracting height of image using `getImageScaledHeight()`. This method returns height of image in pixels and not in user units therefore it still leaves some margin on top.

I tried another approach by setting `pageNumber(i+1)` and `setMarginTop(0)`. But looks like when you set margin, page number doesn't have any effect and all images get added one after another on first page.

I would really appreciate if anyone can provide best way to or a workaround to achieve this.

[PDF #1-Without auto scale flag #2 Auto scale set true on image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xfDZP.png)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

### Solution to add multiple images to PDF at top of each page with scaling.

I figured out solution for this issue. I wanted others who might run into similar issue to benefit from my solution hence I am posting it as an answer instead of commenting on my question.

So it turns out that `getImageScaledHeight()` method doesn't work if auto scaling is turned on using `setAutoScale(true)`. Auto scaling will happen but not until after image has been added to document but to set position of an image at top of the page we need image's scaled height in calling following method

```
image.setFixedPosition(i + 1, 0, PageSize.A4.getHeight()-image.getImageScaledHeight());
```

In order to enable scaling of images to fit on page and also position them at desired location on page you need to

1. **First scale an image using method `image.scaleToFit(fitWidth, fitHeight)`** and then calculate bottom position using scaled
2. Calculate bottom position using **scaled image height (`image.getImageScaledHeight()`) and page height**.

Now, if you want to have margins in your pdf then you will have to change code for scaling an image and setting fixed position accordingly. Following are code sample of solution for both scenarios.

### Solution #1. Multiple images to PDF on separate page at top without margins

```
image.scaleToFit(pdfA4usableWidth, pdfA4usableHeight);
image.setFixedPosition(i + 1, 0, PageSize.A4.getHeight()-image.getImageScaledHeight());
```

[Click here to see code sample with console output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bdjf9.png)

### Solution #2. Multiple images to PDF on separate page at top with margins

```
float leftMargin = document.getLeftMargin(), rightMargin = document.getRightMargin();
float topMargin = document.getTopMargin(), bottomMargin = document.getBottomMargin();
float pdfA4usableWidth = PageSize.A4.getWidth() - leftMargin - rightMargin;
float pdfA4usableHeight = PageSize.A4.getHeight() - topMargin - bottomMargin;

System.out.println("A4 usable width: "+pdfA4usableWidth+", usable height: "+pdfA4usableHeight);

image.scaleToFit(pdfA4usableWidth, pdfA4usableHeight);
image.setFixedPosition(i + 1, 0, PageSize.A4.getHeight()-image.getImageScaledHeight());
```

[Click here to see code sample with console output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NtPrk.png)

PDFs generated...

[Image added to PDF with no margins](https://i.stack.imgur.com/R1bjD.png)

[Image added to PDF with default margins](https://i.stack.imgur.com/St8Cw.png)

[Measurement of margins on PDF](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Xdqgl.png)

Notes:

1. In attached screen shots of PDFs, grey color is just a background of a PDF viewer.
2. Image files are as test1.jpg and test2.jpg to keep this code example simple.

Comment: I've opened SO today willing to update my answer with the same remarks, but you've already done it yourself! :+1:

Answer (score 1):

Let's introduce some more changes to the `MultipleImages` example:

1) (minor) There is no need to create a `Document` with a custom page size, that'd be enough: `Document doc = new Document(pdfDoc);`

2) Let's modify the bottom parameter of the `setFixedPosition` method by extracting the height of the image from the default page height: `image.setFixedPosition(i + 1, 0, PageSize.A4.getHeight()-image.getImageScaledHeight());`

The resultant pdf looks as expected:

[image]

Comment: Thank you for taking time out to answer my question. It doesn't solve my issue but helped me to pinpoint the problem. Your suggested changes (both 1 and 2) are exactly what I had tried to get images at top of the page.  The only difference was I used `code` setAutoScale(true) `code` on my image to fit pdf page.  As I mentioned in my question, I used `code` getImageScaledHeight(). `code` to subtract from A4 height. Turns out that this method is returning original height of the image getImageHeight(), not the height that image will be scaled down to, when it's added to PDF document.